# Retrive Json Data, reformat it and create new endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest, web

What is the best way to get some Json data from a public api such as [British Air quality](https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity) i.e and create a new endpoint with some of the data under a different name like

```
{ 
  "data":[{ 
    "from": "2018-03-17T22:00Z",
    "to": "2018-03-17T22:30Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 251,
      "actual": 250,
      "index": "moderate"
    }
  }]
}
```

To this (I'm dropping some information I don't need)

```
{
"Weather": [
   {"newName": "forecastValue"},
   {"newName2": "ActualValue"}
 ]
}
```

I am facing this problem because I'm working with a third party application which only supports Json if it is formatted like that (2 Values and special name)...

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Decode the JSON to an array -> Re-format it -> Encode it back to JSON -> voila!

Comment: @MehdiBounya   Thanks for the answer, I had something like this in mind... So I'll temporarily save it with PHP and create an endpoint

Comment: I know it is probably overkill, but this is the sort of scenario that [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) manages quite nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution in JavaScript :**

```js
var orginalJSON = { 
  "data":[{ 
    "from": "2018-03-17T22:00Z",
    "to": "2018-03-17T22:30Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 251,
      "actual": 250,
      "index": "moderate"
    }
  }]
};

var newJSON = {
"Weather": [
   {"newName": orginalJSON.data[0].intensity.forecast},
   {"newName2": orginalJSON.data[0].intensity.actual}
 ]
};

console.log(newJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives a slightly different json string as output, but I would say it was more usable than your suggestion

```
<?php
$in = '{
  "data":[{
    "from": "2018-03-17T22:00Z",
    "to": "2018-03-17T22:30Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 251,
      "actual": 250,
      "index": "moderate"
    }
  }]
}';

$jin = json_decode($in);

$out = [];

$out = new stdClass();
$out->weather = ['newName'=>$jin->data[0]->intensity->forecast,
                 'newName2' =>$jin->data[0]->intensity->actual
                ];
$out = json_encode($out);

echo $out;
```

Result

```
{"weather":{"newName":251,"newName2":250}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a) the JavaScript tag you put on the question means you want it in JavaScript, and b) your JSON is in a variable called jsonData...

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var intensityData = dataObj.data[0].intensity;
var outputData = {forecast: intensityData.forecast, actual: intensityData.actual};
var jsonOutput = JSON.stringify(outputData);
```